# vqmod wildcard search using regex

Tags: php, regex, opencart, vqmod

As an example here I am trying to replace all `$this->load->model(*);`, the * represents a wildcard search/replace. What is the correct way to do this in a regex?

```
<operation>
    <search regex="true" position="replace"><![CDATA[ $this->load->model(.*); ]]></search>
    <add><![CDATA[ $this->load->model('catalog/information'); ]]></add>
</operation>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The escaping required should be pretty minimal. You only need to escape the `$` and the parentheses like so

```
<search regex="true" position="replace"><![CDATA[~\$this->load->model\(.*?\);~]]></search>
```

Also as you've rightly done in your answer to this, you need to add a delimiter (I find `~` is far less likely to be in a string than `/` hence using that instead)