# Get Image file name using regex wildcard search vqmod

Tags: regex, opencart, vqmod

I am wanting to remove the icons from the h1 title element in opencart admin panel. I'm trying to use an asterisk as a wildcard for the file name, but it's not working out. 
The docs says the search data:

`<h1><img src="view/image/*.png" alt="" /> <?php echo $heading_title; ?></h1>`

should be a valid regex pattern, though I'm not familiar with regex. How can I do this correctly in vqmod?

```
<file name="admin/view/template/*/*.tpl">
    <operation>
        <search regex="true" position="replace"><![CDATA[
            <h1><img src="view/image/*.png" alt="" /> <?php echo $heading_title; ?></h1>
        ]]></search>
        <add><![CDATA[      
            <h1><?php echo $heading_title; ?></h1>
        ]]></add>
    </operation>
</file>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In vQmod, the regex still needs to have its delimiters. You are also better off just using a generic search for the `<h1>` since you are setting it to just the heading title.

```
<file name="admin/view/template/*/*.tpl">
    <operation>
        <search regex="true" position="replace"><![CDATA[~<h1>.*?</h1>~]]></search>
        <add><![CDATA[<h1><?php echo $heading_title; ?></h1>]]></add>
    </operation>
</file>
```

Comment: I added `error="skip"` to operation and it worked. Thanks Jay

Answer (score 1):

In regex, an asterisk `*` is a quantifier which means match zero or more times.
I think you want to match anything, one or more times. You do that with `.+`. Ofcourse you want it ungreedy, so the final pattern is `.+?`.

- `.` : match anything
- `+` : a quantifier which means match one or more times
- `?` : `+` followed by `?` means to match ungreedy

---

Let's apply the above in the code:

```
<h1><img src="view/image/.+?\.png" alt="" /> <?php echo preg_quote($heading_title); ?></h1>
```

- We need to escape the dot in `\.png`
- We'll use [`preg_quote()`](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-quote.php) to escape properly regex reserved characters in the `$heading_title` variable

Comment: Thanks. In my post I point out the the whole string needs to be a "valid regex pattern". How do I apply that, to this html with the wildcard applied to the image name `<h1><img src="view/image/*.png" alt="" /> <?php echo $heading_title; ?></h1> `

Comment: The search data needs to remain as it appears in the source. If you see this post it might help you understand what I mean http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16624973/vqmod-wildcard-search-using-regex - I need a similar solution, not for a PHP string, but for the html I posted in my previous comment.

Comment: @Lea Have you tried the solution ? Otherwise I shouldn't have answered since I've no idea what environment this is ...

Comment: @HamZa - The php is not executed - it's static text